# Block Google script for other user

Tags: google-sheets

I have already made a lot of google script, but now I am looking for the following functionality.

Sometimes there is important information in a script that other users are not allowed to read how can I block access to the script but that the script can be used

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to not use it in your spreadsheet. eg. import data into a sheet with script and export output back to the public sheet.

Another way would be to pack your script into extension/addon